Thunderbird keeps redirecting to wrong login site
I have a .edu email (Gmail account). Every time I try to add this account to Thunderbird, it assumes it is an Outlook account and therefore redirects me to the Outlook login page. How can I fix this?

Thanks! Unfortunately, my university page didn't let me log in this way--but I did find a similar workaround: I chose IMAP (POP) + STARTTLS (TLS/SSL) + OAuth2 (OAuth2) imap.gmail.com:993 (smtp.gmail.com:587) for the incoming (outgoing) settings respectively.

Sounds like your university has incorrect autoconfiguration DNS entries. You could alert their IT department to the issue.
